# fontWeight Chinese not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

`fontWeight` doesn't work in Chinese, English works.

Is there any good solution please?

```kotlin
Text(text = "Hello", fontWeight = FontWeight(100))    // Work

Text(text = "你好", fontWeight = FontWeight(100))      // Not working
```